# Use a Map data structure in OCL

Tags: uml, ocl

how can i use a Map in OCL. For example i want to get all bills for user c1 and my Map 'purchases' looks like  `Map <Date, Bill>`.

c1.purchases.Bill? Is this possible?

regards

Comment: You mean something like https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/166172/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to synthesize a map in OCL from a Set(Tuple(K,V)) is something that I and others have been guilty of advocating. A Map(K,V) maintains a single unique V entry per K, whereas a Set(Tuple(K,V)) may have many V's for the same K; not the same at all.

Eclipse OCL therefore has a Map(K,V) as part of its modeled standard library that might eventually make it into the standard.

Regards

Ed Willink